# Hauppauge HD PVR 2 to ffmpeg on OS X

Tags: macos, usb, ffmpeg, dev, hauppauge

How can I use ffmpeg to capture video and audio from a Hauppauge HD PVR 2 connected to my Mac via USB?

I have seen a couple posts [here](http://forums.unixhub.net/showthread.php?tid=255) and [here](http://dwellertech.blogspot.com/2013/05/raspberry-pi-and-hd-pvr.html) about doing this on a Unix machine (not OS X) using `ffmpeg -i /dev/video0` and I was hoping this would also work on OS X, but I don't see any /dev/videoN files when I plug in the device via USB. Not sure, but looks like the missing key might be that I need to load a "kernel module" to recognize the device. I'm no expert with kernel modules/extensions or device files so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction here. Thanks!

Note: the script mentioned in the first link is located at pastebin.com/jv8fd7Bq (I "need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links").

Answer (score 1):

The solution I am working on is to use AppleScript to automate the [HDPVRCapture](http://www.hdpvrcapture.com/wordpress/) (costs money) GUI, then post-process the resulting file using ffmpeg.

I have managed to press the "Record" button of HDPVRCapture using this AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "HDPVRCapture"
        click button "Record" of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

And the following AppleScript to press the "Stop" button:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "HDPVRCapture"
        click button "Stop" of sheet 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

I will then use a python script to tie these together and call ffmpeg for post-processing.